# How to set (or get) height of audio element in firefox android?

Tags: css, firefox, html5-audio

I have a HTML5 audio element embedded in a div tag and i set height of this element like this:

```
<div style="border:solid 2px red">
    <audio style="height:30px; display:block" controls="controls" >
    </audio>
</div>
```

This code works correctly in all new browsers except Firefox android:

[image: result in chrome android: correct] [image: result in firefox android: incorrect].

(left image: chrome android; right image: firefox android)

But when I use js function `document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].offsetHeight()` it returns 30px.

what can I do?

Comment: `<div style="border: 2px solid red; max-height: 30px; display: table;"><audio style="max-height:30px; display: table-cell" controls height="30"></audio></div>`

Comment: Thank @zer00ne, but your code dose not work correctly, too.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it might not. I can't test FF Android so I commented rather than answered. Good luck, sir.